# Radio Button-selection based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i select a radio button with its value is the only one which is unique via JS. This seems to be little odd, but i need to. the Html code is as follows

```
<td class="Customer_Name"><table>
<td>
     <input name="Name" tabindex="4" id="Name" type="radio" value="01">John</td>    
     <input name="Name" tabindex="4" id="Name" type="radio" value="02">Sam</td> 
     <input name="Name" tabindex="4" id="Name" type="radio" value="03">Fred</td>
     <input name="Name" tabindex="4" id="Name"  type="radio" value="04">Peter</td>              
<td>
```

Comment: Why all of your elements have same ID.  ID should be unique for a good HTML structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have same `id` for multiple elements. `id` should be unique.

You can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with attribute-value selector.

```
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][value="02"]')
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/j0zcxodv/)

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][value="02"]').checked = true;
```

```html
<td class="Customer_Name">
  <table>
    <td>
      <input name="Name" type="radio" value="01" />John</td>
    <td>
      <input name="Name" type="radio" value="02" />Sam</td>
    <td>
      <input name="Name" type="radio" value="03" />Fred</td>
    <td>
      <input name="Name" type="radio" value="04" />Peter</td>
    <td>
```

---

Using jQuery

```
$('input[type="radio"][value="02"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @justin Check the demo, use `checked` property on radio button

Comment: thanks, i just saw a web page with this kind of structure and am new to to html and JS. Your code worked and Thanks for the knowledge.